# Does changing an array copy data?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

If I defined a global array of strings like:

```
char* arr[] = {
    "abc",
    "def",
    "gh",
    NULL
};
```

and then I tried to change the first element in the main() function like:

```
arr[0]="something"
```

Does changing elements of an array copy data?
Did this make a copy of the original arr[0] or?

Comment: This should be declared as `const char*` since you aren't allowed to modify the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `arr` contain pointers to cstrings as `arr` is declared to be an array of pointers to `char`. The elements themselves do *not* actually contain the cstrings.

So, when you do `arr[0] = "something"`, the data stored at `arr[0]` is overwritten with the address of `something`. At this point, there is one instance each of `abc` and `something`, but, you can't reach `abc` using `arr[0]` any more.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically equivalent to this:

```
char* arr[4];

arr[0] = "abc";
arr[1] = "def",
arr[2] = "gh",
arr[3] = NULL;

arr[0] = "something";
```

The original string "abc" is left untouched, but also inaccessible, unless you save a pointer to it. So this:

```
arr[0] = "abc";
char *s = arr[0];
arr[0] = "something";
puts(s);
```

will print "abc";

Comment: @Gerhardh Of course. Thanks.